# Azure VM with wordpress + mysql

Tags: wordpress, azure, docker

I'm doing some R&D and created VM on Azure by selecting Wordpress + mysql and publisher is Docker.

I'm facing problem in connecting to this VM Tried WinSCP and Putty but no luck. Looks like this is something different.

I follow below step to add this VM.

Azure Portal > Virtual Machine > Add > Compute > wordpress + mysql > Created this with Resource Manager Model.

After this VM is created and 22 port default rule is showing open in Endpoint but when I'm trying to connect using WinSCP or putty by pointing to IP/DNS name(wp-xxxx.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com) of this machine its not connecting.

Can someone please provide any link or instructions to connect to this VM?

Thanks,
Imran

Comment: is it a docker container?

Comment: I think so but not sure. I see DockerExtension is showing in extensions of this VM.

Comment: You should be able to SSH into your Docker Host VM, it should be a linux VM running docker-engine. from there you can manage your containers. for starters give me the command that you created the VM with.

Comment: I added VM directly from Azure Virtual Machines -> Compute. Yes, it is a Linux machine that is why I tried SSH but looks like 22 port is not reachable even 22 port is open from Azure Endpoint.

Comment: You should be able to ssh, check your settings, its a full VM not a container

Comment: That's the issue. I still can't connect. Checked 22 port using telnet and its failing. Let me edit my question what I installed on Azure then it might help you to understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

Go to Network Security Group and open port 22, this will allow you to SSH.

[image]